# Returning multiple results from one row

Tags: mysql

I have a set of MySQL data similar to the following:

```
| id | type       | start               | end                 |
===============================================================
|  1 |      event | 2011-11-01T00:00:00 | 2012-01-02T00:00:00 |
|  2 |    showing | 2012-11-04T00:00:00 | 2012-11-04T00:00:00 |
|  3 | conference | 2012-12-01T00:00:00 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00 |
|  4 |     event2 | 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | 2012-01-01T00:00:00 |
```

I want to retrieve events within a certain date range, but I also want to return individual results for each row that has a time span of more than one day. What's the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: In other words, I want to return two results from the **event** row, four results from the **conference** row and a single result for all the others.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to access the MySQL data at the moment, if not PHP?

Comment: Is changing the start/end fields to Unix timestamps a possibility?

Comment: If you want to return a result set with the same columns for 2 different conditions do a UNION or use UNION ALL on the SELECT. Alternatively use an OR expression.

Comment: What you basically can do is use a second (generated on the fly) table with days and join that on your data table.

Comment: It's not clear at all, what you want to do. What individual results?

Comment: @Andrew: He meant he don't want to implement the `WHERE` part of the SQL query in PHP.

Comment: I figured out a solution with UNION thanks to Emmad's suggestion: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/c1ac7/9

The only problem is that it isn't working in my real-world situation because there are other tables and joins involved. I'll try to post an example of the problem I'm now faced with. If anyone has any suggestions for a better solution I'm all ears. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE START BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-03'
OR END BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-03'    
OR TO_DAYS(end) - TO_DAYS(start) > 1
```

I have created it for testing on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dda1/14/0)

Comment: user714965, This gives me the results from a date range, but in your example I would be looking to return 3 results for events, 4 results fro conference and 1 result for showing. And I want to do this in a single query. If unions are necessary I'd love to see how it can be done, but am also wondering if there is a better way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.